# What does GCCs conversion function &operator int(); do?

Tags: c++, reference, type-conversion, clang

With g++, this is a legal declaration:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo();
    &operator int();  // this fails with Clang   
};
```

This is a simplified example of my real code, which looks more like

```
template <class VAR_TYPE> class Foo : public Bar<VAR_TYPE>
{
  public:   
    Foo();
    // [...] more constructors here

    &operator const VAR_TYPE () const;  // this fails with Clang

    // [...] more stuff (a lot)
};
```

Trying to compile this with Clang yields the following error:

> error: cannot specify any part of a return type in the declaration of
>   a conversion function; put the complete type after 'operator'

I've found arguments that the GCCs use of `&` here is forbidden, as it violates the language definition 12.3.2.1

> [...] No return type can be specified. If a conversion function is a
>   member function, the  type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is
>   “function taking no parameter returning conversion-type-id”. [...]

**Question 1.**
What exactly does the GCC implementation do? From my testing, I suspect it to be equivalent to `operator int& ();`, but please correct me if I'm wrong or if I miss some additional functionality.

**Question 2.**
In my (legacy) code, it's actually `&operator const VAR_TYPE() const;`. Given my assumption from Question 1 is true, this would be equivalent to `operator const VAR_TYPE&() const;`. What could be the purpose of returning a const reference instead of a non-reference copy and can this be somehow exploited to give write-access to underlying data-structures like array/vector-elements?

**Question 3.**
Is this really illegal by the language definition? The cited text only talks about return types. `&` is not a type. It's a lexical element which needs to be combined with a normal type-specifier to become a type. But I can't find an extensive explanation of `&` in the language definition.

Comment: I'd wager this is a bug in GCC's parser, especially considering `-pedantic` doesn't give a warning.

Comment: Given this 'bug' is stable for more than 8 years of GCC, I'd say it's either intentional or 'won't fix'. Still I'm interested in what it actually does.

Comment: Bug happens even for non templated class.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, was just meant to make it clear it's not related to type. I'll clearify this ...

Comment: It would be nice if you posted **REAL CODE**. I corrected one syntactical error (semicolon) plus one looks-like-error (in the `template` part). But there's no guarantee that the resulting more valid-ish code is the actual code that your compiler compiles. Please do keep in mind that SO readers are, mostly, not telephaths. We can't see what you see, and we can't reasonably guess whether `TYPE` is something like `int`, or as specified by the actual code you posted, something like `5`.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking a reproducible example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the code currently in the question reproduces the error for me, using godbolt  (clang rejects, gcc accepts)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question now contains the abbreviated real code. It's less readable, harder to understand and adds zero more information. Hope you are happy now.

Comment: gcc seems to think/allow that the preceding `&` causes the operator to return a reference: https://godbolt.org/g/NZw1dk

Comment: @Chaos_99 I agree with you that the shortened code is better in this case, but the guy with the ridiculous handle does have a valid point: you should post code that compiles (if you are claiming that it does).

Comment: Further experimentation seems to indicate `&operator int()` is semantically equivalent, more or less, to `operator int&()`, however, it has a different mangled name (de-mangles as `operator int()`).

Comment: I'm tired of looking at GCC parser code, but from what I can gather, it's parsing the decl-specifier-seq as optional, finding nothing, then taking the & as a ptr-operator and continuing on with the declaration from there.

Comment: Retracted the close vote. In order to find out what g++ parses the declaration as, just output the type of the thingy. E.g. as a diagnostic for the declaration `char* x = foo{};`. Wait, wait, ... I can do that! Done. So, it's parsed as `foo::operator int&()`. Now we know that. That wasn't so difficult, was it? Just provide us with real code, and we figure things out. Ususally. Remember.

Comment: @davmac, From what I could tell from the code, GCC sees the & and initially makes a reference declarator, but when it parses the rest of the declarator (`operator int()`), it doesn't have that information handy, so it mangles based on just that part, without the reference.

Comment: @Chaos_99, Regarding being around for 8 years, think of it this way. In other contexts, a ptr-operator is used such as `int(&arr)[N]`, or `void(*foo)()`, or `void(*)()`. It's in the middle of the declaration, and followed by an optional identifier/extra qualifiers and the rest of the declaration. Here, we have a very special case. `&operator int()` has `&` being followed by an identifier (`operator int`) and the rest of the declaration. It's tricky, hence I wouldn't be surprised if no one ever found it and brought it up.

Comment: @chris Having this backed up with some language definition reference to clearly show its a "bug" was the intention of question 1. I lack confidence in compiler knowledge to report it as bug to GCC without. (But feel free to do so yourself.)

Comment: @Chaos_99, No production for a declaration can start with `&`. It's that simple. Unfortunately, it would be a lot to cite because of its nature (not being included in the grammar rather than a line specifically allowing it) and because the tree of production rules for *member-declaration* is quite large.

Comment: The GCC bugreport: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79318